# Как растянуть блок на весь экран bootstrap?

Tags: bootstrap

```
     <div class="container">
            <div class="row" >
                <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-4 col-xl-4 col-12" >
                    <div class="BLOCK">
                       <div class="icon headline-block">
                          <span class="icon-home icon_color-blue"></span>
                          <h5 class="headline_info">Заглавие</h5>
                       </div>
                       <p class="selection-select">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipiscing elit sed tempor incididunt ut laboret dolore magna ut consequat siad esqudiat dolordLorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipiscing elit sed tempor incididunt ut laboret dolore magna ut consequat siad esqudiat dolord</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
          </div>
        </div>
```

Вот такой вот вопрос... как сделать , чтоб при большом экране размер блока Block был один к примеру 200px , а во время маленького он растягивался на весь ?

```
  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/b5ehE.png
```

Стиль

```
 .BLOCK{
           width: 200px;    
        }
```

Comment: блок все равно остается 200пикселей ,а мне надо чтоб растянулся.

Comment: там только один стиль ... block{ width 200px}

Comment: в самом верху bootstrap внизу css

Comment: да да да ...я знаю... это мне пока что не важно... мне нужно блок растянуть , потом уже всё остальное ...p.s.это я сюда так написал

Comment: https://codepen.io/nilsons20000/pen/rgLrRX вот... уменьшите..у меня не работает

Comment: да, и вот как сделать так, чтоб на маленьком экране он растягивался, так как на меленьком там он тоже те 200px

Comment: я в курсе, что если не влезает то упадет...я знаю как css сделать чтоб при одном размере экрана блок  был одним размером , а при другом другим ..media. Сейчас меня интересует bootstrap...

Comment: в вашей разметке используется `container` всё что находиться внутри не будет на всю ширину экрана.
Пробуйте через `container-fluid` или переопределяйте стили для `container`

Comment: не важно или это container или container-fluid... и там  и там при маленьком экране он на всё ширину, а когда ставишь блоку width то и не  там и не там он на всю ширину при маленьком экране не становится